# StatusBar Items displayed verticaly

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am wondering if there is a way to display StatusBarItem within a StatusBar in a Top to Bottom (or Bottom to Top) way instead of the usual left to right. Something like:

```
<StatusBar Orientation="Vertical">
    <StatusBarItem Content="I'm over the second item." />
    <StatusBarItem Content="I'm bellow the first item." />
</StatusBar>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ItemsPanel` property:

```
    <StatusBar>
        <Button>A</Button>
        <Button>B</Button>
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
    </StatusBar>
```